# use query string in URL to display content on the page

Tags: urls, content, parameter, query-string

I'd like to say something on my page based on what page the person got there from. I can set up the link to that page to be:

```
www.example.com/page?parameter=myparameter
```

Is there a way I can access that parameter so that I can have it show on the page, somewhere in my content?

Comment: Sorry I understand that the answers are examples, but I find it important to note that they should not be used as-is. User input (like query string parameters) should **never be echoed unsanitized** to prevent [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Non-persistent)! **All answers so far are vulnerable to XSS** and should at least include a warning.

Comment: For a **SAFE way** to implement this, [use this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/url-params/) - or [browse the code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/url-params/) of the plugin on github.

Answer (score 6):

Per the OP's answer within their question:

> With your help and some Googling, I put together a shortcode that returns the value of any url parameter. Here it is:

```
//THIS IS A CUSTOM SHORTCODE TO DISPLAY A PARAMETER FROM THE URL
function URLParam( $atts ) {  
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'param' => 'param',
    ), $atts ) );
    return $_GET[$param];  
}
add_shortcode('URLParam', 'URLParam');
```

I use the shortcode like this to get the `trip_type` from my URL:

```
[URLParam param='trip_type']
```

Comment: This helped me, thanks! How do I get values from form post data instead of query string?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a PHP session, look in the query object for the request, or use $_GET with your url, but it's not for sensitive information...

Something like this;

Grab the trip name from the URL

`$tripname = $_GET['tripname'];`

Use it in your heading;

`if(isset($tripname)) echo '<h1>Plan Your Trip To ' .$tripname. '</h1>';`

Comment: Thanks! This is not sensitive info. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This might help you out : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

Comment: Thanks! Can I put that straight onto the page, or does it need to go into a template file?

Comment: Depends where you need it - if it's only showing on a page that runs on one template, you would put it there. Where is the information coming from, and where will it end up?

Comment: The story is like this: I have a lot of 'trip pages', each of which has information about a certain trip we run. Then, they click "register", and it takes them to a page with a registration form (gravity forms). I'd like the page (or else the description on the top of the form) to say "Fill out this form to register for the xxxx trip".

Comment: So I added to the url of the register button on each trip page, www.website.com/registration?trip=tripname.

Comment: Updated the answer above, see what you think.

Comment: So where would I put that code?

Comment: I would also like to use the same functionality on another form page, where they request for us to sent them an itinerary. Would your solution work? Maybe a shortcode would be a better idea??

Comment: Coding a shortcode will require more work and time than this, so it depends what you want to do overall. The code I mentioned would go on the page the form is on. If they are on a particular template, like page.php, it would go there.

Comment: They are both on the same template, but I want there to be different text around it. Can that be done without a shortcode?

Comment: Or, do you know where I can find "creating shortcodes for dummies" or something of the sort?

Comment: I suggest spending some time on the WP Codex and reading up on shortcodes. There is some good stuff online. You could switch between two pieces of text in the same template, but the conditional statement would be another matter.

Comment: I will take a look. What do you mean by "You could switch between two pieces of text in the same template"?

Comment: You'd need a condition. Check out "if" statements ;)

Comment: Thanks! With your help, and some googling, I put together a basic shortcode that will return the value of a specific parameter. Updated code above

Answer (score 2):

Here's another great way to accomplish this. This won't require shortcodes and will automatically update each page you create where there parameter "trip" is present!
1) Navigate to your theme folder and open **functions.php** (or create it if it's missing)
2) Add the following code and save:

```
<?php 
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_trip_filter' );

    function my_trip_filter( $content ) {
        if ( isset($_REQUEST['trip']) && is_single() ) {
            $content = "<h1>Fill out this form to register for the " . $_REQUEST['trip'] . " trip</h1>" . $content;
        }

        return $content;

    }
?>
```

This code uses **the_content** filter to override each time you use the function **the_content()** function to print your blog information. It detects whether or not the page requested is a single page/post and not the archive. Additional logic or overrides can be added to it. Just make sure you return **$content** and whatever message you desire will be returned to the screen.
Enjoy!